# Unable to install RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ssl, rvm

I follow the website's instructions and call the following from my terminal

```
Grahams-MacBook-Pro:~ Graham$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Earlier the site was down, thanks to @bdesham for informing me about this.

Now that it is back up,

I am getting the following errors.

```
Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.

ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: follow this guide : http://ryanbigg.com/2011/06/mac-os-x-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Comment: Can you provide more context for the error? I.e. include more of the console output related to the rubygems installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the website is just plain down. Try again in thirty minutes?

Comment: lol you are probably right, I didn't think of that since the instructions page had loaded, so I didn't think that it would go done 15 seconds later lol

Comment: I will update you once the site is restored to see if it worked

Comment: See my solution to see how I solved it. Since you did help me, though, I will upvote you and say yours is the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ruby on Rails One Click and it worked well for me. http://rubyosx.rubyforge.org/

It sets it up quite easily (both Ruby and Rails) without any error. I highly recommend it, and no, I do not work for them lol.